# Filter an array to remove duplicates in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've scoured through many posts and have been working on this problem for too long. The gist is that I want to filter an array if there are duplicate object id's and return the object with the lower value or "val", otherwise return the original element.

Start with:

**edited input for clarification

```
let input = [
    {"id": 1, "val": 3},
    {"id": 2, "val": 1},
    {"id": 3, "val": 4},
    {"id": 1, "val": 0}
]

function removeDuplicates(array, propertyName) {
    // where propertyName is "id"
}
```

The result of the function should be:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "val": 0},
    {"id": 2, "val": 1},
    {"id": 3, "val": 4}
]
```

Comment: is `val` always `0`?  or it's not important in duplication?

Comment: The naive implementation would be exactly as if you were doing it on a piece of paper. Would you be able that manually if you are given a moderate size list (like 50 elements) with pen and paper?

Comment: @Salman not necessarily, and you only use "val" when you have to objects that have the same "id". When comparing, the object with the lower "val" would be returned in the array.

Comment: @Tyler Not sure if I understood your question, but does my snippet work for you or should it be the other way round?

Comment: I would suggest use Lodash uniqBy
Which you can find it here.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very common approach to such issues is to create a temporary object that uses the common property as keys and a full object as values.

Once you loop through the data array once and build the object then it is a simple process to put the values into resultant array

```js
let input = [
    {"id": 1, "val": 0},
    {"id": 2, "val": 0},
    {"id": 3, "val": 0},
    {"id": 1, "val": 1}
]

let tmp = {}

input.forEach(o=> {
  tmp[o.id] = tmp[o.id] || o;
  // assign lower value if applicable
  if( o.val < tmp[o.id].val){         
    tmp[o.id].val = o.val;
  }
});

let res = Object.values(tmp);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach is to simply use a temp object to store all the objects in the array with the ids as object keys, since object key can't be duplicate, multiple occurrence will simply override each other till finally you will just have to convert the object back into an array using `Object.values(obj)`.

```
var input = [
    {"id": 1, "val": 0},
    {"id": 2, "val": 0},
    {"id": 3, "val": 0},
    {"id": 1, "val": 1}
];
function removeDuplicates(array, propertyName) {
    var tmp = {};
    array.forEach(function (v) {
        if (tmp[v[propertyName]] == null) {
            tmp[v[propertyName]] = v;
        } else if (v.val < tmp[v[propertyName]].val)
            tmp[v[propertyName]] = v;
        }
    });
    return Object.values(tmp);
}
```

Use this:

```
removeDuplicates(input, "id");
```

To return the following:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "val": 0},
    {"id": 2, "val": 0},
    {"id": 3, "val": 0}
]
```

Comment: Testing the code, it's returning the { "id": 1, "val": 1 }. Switching the "val"s around, it looks like this code produces the second { "id": 1 } every time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and then check in the accumulator if current value is smaller than one you have already saved.

```js
let input = [
    {"id": 1, "val": 0},
    {"id": 2, "val": 0},
    {"id": 3, "val": 0},
    {"id": 1, "val": 1}
]

function removeDuplicates(array, propertyName) {
    return array.reduce((acc, cv) => {
        if (acc.hasOwnProperty(cv[propertyName])) {
            if (cv.val < acc[cv[propertyName]].val)
                acc[cv[propertyName]] = cv;
        } else
            acc[cv[propertyName]] = cv;
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
console.log(removeDuplicates(input,"id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter` and `.map`:

```
inputs
    .filter(object => object.id == propertyValue) // get only the objects you want
    .map(object => object.val)                    // convert each object to it's value
    .sort()                                       // sort it
    [0]                                           // and get the first (meaning smallest) element
```

Comment: This looks very neat, but I'm not sure how it works! Can you explain what's going on in the object.id == propertyValue bit? It doesn't run for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/12bozrnv/1/

Comment: @Beejamin, the jsfiddle doesn't run because propertyValue is undefined. But in that line of code I wrote, I used the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The filter function takes a function that returns true if the object satisfied the filter algorithm. Here's an example where I filter for numbers only: `myArray.filter(x => typeof x == 'number')`. This returns only numbers from the myArray array.

Comment: `propertyValue` is a placeholder? Gotcha.

Comment: @Beejamin It was a reference to the OP's code. His function is given `propertyName`. Though I accidentally used `propertyValue`.

Comment: I've tried to adjust this to make a runnable example, but I can't get it to work. I'm not super familiar with ECMA6 conventions though, so it could be that. Would you mind expanding your example to a runnable snippet?

Comment: @Beejamin check out the codepen here: https://codepen.io/AskYous/pen/WXORqB. It works. I also put a way to do it without ECMA6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158906/discussion-between-beejamin-and-askyous).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to build a new hash out of the lowest values, then just return the values of that hash.

```js
var input = [
  {"id": 1, "val": 0},
  {"id": 2, "val": 0},
  {"id": 3, "val": 0},
  {"id": 1, "val": 1}
];

function minFromArray(ar) {
  //Object.values returns the values of a hash as an array.
  return Object.values(ar.reduce(function(acc, obj){
    //If this is the first instance of the ID, or the value is lower than the existing
    if (typeof(acc[obj['id']]) == 'undefined' || obj['val'] < acc[obj['id']]) {
      acc[obj['id']] = obj;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}));
}

console.log(minFromArray(input));
```